# PowerPoint ActiveX text boxes and labels split in to 2 parts during presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

When I add a text box or label from Powerpoint's developer tab, they look fine until I run the presentation and then they split into 2 boxes, one where it should be but is unfunctioning and another one above and left of the first that allows actions.

I haven't tried anything as I have no idea why it is acting this way

I simply want a control that I can activate to pop up an input box and to store the result. It happens with labels and text boxes as soon as I assign some vba code to it. The input box / vba works fine but having the ghost box ruins the page layout.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDepy.png)

presentation mode:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOLiQ.png)

Comment: Can you attach a photo before and after toggling presentation view?

Comment: Super User or Answers.microsoft.com would be a better place for this question. You're seeing a video driver problem. You may be able to fix it by installing a recent video driver from your computer manufacturer. You can also try File>Options>Advanced>Display and checking Disable Slide Show hardware graphics acceleration.

Comment: Thanks John. Video drivers are up to date but disabling hardware acceleration fixed the problem. Many thanks. I put this up on Microsoft's forum but still haven't had a reply despite it going up there first.

Answer (score 0):

On the monitor that I was presenting on, I changed the display property scale settings from 100% to 125% and the issue resolved.